# Expected declaration of a conditional statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, conditional-statements

I now set up my system of putting the answer in 1 of 4 choices but a weird error appeared:

```
     var optionAnswer:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
if optionAnswer == 0 {                    // Expected declaration
   optionA.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
if optionAnswer == 1 {
   optionB.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
if optionAnswer == 2 {
   optionC.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
if optionAnswer == 3 {
   optionD.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
```

the error only appeared on the first conditional and it didn't specify what I needed to do. How do I fix this?

full code:

```
     import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var numA: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var operation: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var numB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secretAnsarrrrr: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var optionA: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var optionB: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var optionC: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var optionD: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var level: UILabel!
@IBAction func startTest(sender: UIButton) {
    var question:Int = 1
    func generateQuestion() {
        var answer:Float = 0.0
        var randomoperation:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
        if randomoperation == 0 {
            operation.text = "+"
        }
        if randomoperation == 1 {
            operation.text = "-"
        }
        if randomoperation == 2 {
            operation.text = "X"
        }
        if randomoperation == 3 {
            operation.text = "/"
        }
        var randomNumber:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(1000)
        var randomNumber2:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(1000)
        // 1000 is my maximum number for now.
        randomNumber += 1
        randomNumber2 += 1
        func identifyVal() {
            if randomNumber < randomNumber2 {
                var between:UInt32 = 1000 - randomNumber2
                randomNumber = randomNumber2 + arc4random_uniform(between - 1)
                //making sure that randomNumber is not smaller than randomNumber2, therefore all results are positive.
            }
        }
        if operation.text == "/" {
            identifyVal()

            answer = round(Float(randomNumber)/Float(randomNumber2))
        }

        if operation.text == "+" {
            answer = Float(randomNumber + randomNumber2)
        }
        if operation.text == "-" {
            identifyVal()
            answer = Float(randomNumber - randomNumber2)
        }
        if operation.text == "x" {
            answer = Float(randomNumber * randomNumber2)
        }
        secretAnsarrrrr.text = "\(answer)"
        numA.text = String(Int(randomNumber))
        numB.text = String(Int(randomNumber2))
    }
    generateQuestion()
}
var optionAnswer:UInt32 = arc4random_uniform(4)
if optionAnswer == 0 {
optionA.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
if optionAnswer == 1 {
optionB.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
if optionAnswer == 2 {
optionC.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
if optionAnswer == 3 {
optionD.text = secretAnsarrrrr.text
}
var correct:Bool?
@IBAction func answerA(sender: UIButton) {
    if optionAnswer == 0 {
        correct = true
    } else {
        correct = false
    }
}
@IBAction func answerB(sender: UIButton) {
    if optionAnswer == 1 {
        correct = true
    } else {
        correct = false
    }
}
@IBAction func answerC(sender: UIButton) {
    if optionAnswer == 2 {
        correct = true
    } else {
        correct = false
    }
}
@IBAction func answerD(sender: UIButton) {
    if optionAnswer == 3 {
        correct = true
    } else {
        correct = false
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: If you haven't already done it, set xcode to debug mode. It often won't show the error on the right line when not in debug mode. Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme

Comment: You need to move it inside viewDidLoad

Comment: Putting it inside viewDidLoad doesn't work, logically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long shot- but did you erase a function on that line earlier? If so, comment out the first line, and then erase the "//". Xcode sometimes gets confused.

Side Note: using a switch may work better. Also, consider putting this inside a struct, this would allow you to define a method randomAnswer() that acts on the questions, and then just reference the method in your view. You could also put the different options as Enums as theres only ever 4 of them. :)

Comment: I added the '//' after I pasted it here, and I didn't erase a function

Comment: I know we're not supposed to ask for more code-- but if you could tell us what code you have just before - may explain why you're receiving an 'expected declaration'. Check out if you have an open '{' somewhere before it. For some reasons it's expecting you to set a declaration. It's also possible your code is just in the wrong area as it seems to be correct syntax

Comment: Another alternative: Maybe set your questions in the form of:
`var questionArray = ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3", "answer 4"];
questionArray[Int(arc4random_uniform(4))] = secretAnsarr.text`
Again, by doing it like this (or creating an enum and/or a switch) your best bet it to put this in a struct `struct Name { //code }` and call the randomizer as a method from your ViewController

Comment: It returns the same error "expected declaration" on the when I called the array, also how to you call a struct method?

Comment: Okay: Solved. Click before the if statement and backspace all the way to the previous open bracket, and then click enter. Should fix. I think you put a bunch of spaces instead of hitting enter and it confused the system

Comment: Basically, you shouldn't have all this logic inside your ViewController. You should put it all in a different file (Check out MVC to learn more about why). Inside one of those new folders you could say struct NameOfStruct { //same logic you wrote out func randomizer() {//arc4random randomizer}. This way, you can always refer back to it instead of having so much code and just say var questionSix = NameOfStruct() and then questionSix.randomizer()

Comment: The expected declaration error went to the part where I defined optionAnswer

Comment: I only needed to use the function once

Comment: Okay, it's kind of difficult to truly get to the bottom of this, as most of this code should not be in the View Controller. Look up how to make models. That said, I think the issue is that this part of the code is not inside a function so it's not told when to run,etc.. I fixed it by encasing it in a new function func test() { // the if statement up to before declaring the variable correct} and this fixed the problem. Is your code compiling okay? Also try make a build and put a breaker on that line to see if it works without. but I think the issue is that this code is stranded.

Comment: I put it inside the test function but the "Expected declaration" error went on the the place I called the function "test()".

Comment: Yes, because now this function is stranded. You need to take this logic (and the rest of the logic) and put it in a diff swift file as Struct's so that you can just reference it.

Comment: Well I created a new file but when I referenced it, it gave me logic.type does not have a member named optionAnswer while I clearly declared it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84236/discussion-between-avi-zolty-and-justsoft).